# Show Homepage (only) Hits Count

Tags: plugins, templates, statistics

I need a counter to put in my theme (using php) or widget to show homepage view counts
I've tried "Cystats" but i couldn't get 'only' homepage hits by it
how can I do this ?

(there is a idea to show how many times website has been opened -sessions counts- for example- but i couldn't find any counter to do that , it's ok to find a way to show that instead of homepage counts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the counter (PHP or otherwise) to the template file for the home page.  This will be either `home.php` or `index.php` depending on how you have things set up.

If you want to instead add it in the footer, enclose the code inside a conditional tag to detect whether or not you're on the home page:

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
    // ... put your tracking code here.
}
```